# VS2013 won't open wix file (.wxs) - hang on "Opening the file"

Tags: visual-studio-2013, wix, freeze, wix3.7, wix3.8

Installed wix3.8 and tried to open .wxs file (Wix project) in vs2013 (update 3).
Pop up with "Opening the file" appears and hangs.
Tried also with wix37.
Tried to restart VS2013.
Did anyone encounter that

Comment: I opened new project and copy the .wxs content to there...and it worked